# How To Prevent Queued Job From Executing After Failure?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-queue

I have configured my supervisor worker to attempt laravel queued job 3 times in case of failure. Below is the sample of my worker config.

```
[program:laravel-worker]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php home/vagrant/Code/lead_reactor/artisan queue:work database --sleep=3 --tries=3 --daemon
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=vagrant
numprocs=8
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=home/vagrant/Code/lead_reactor/storage/logs/laravel-worker.log
```

But I do have a specific laravel job queue that I want to be executed only once regardless if there is a failure or none. I want to prevent the future attempts of job execution if there is failure without changing my worker config.

Below is the structure of my job class.

```
class SendBugReports extends Job implements SelfHandling, ShouldQueue
{
    use InteractsWithQueue, SerializesModels;

    protected $bugReports;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->bugReports = BugReport::all();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        //job processes...
    }
}
```

Any help will greatly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may check the number of attempts that have been made to run the job using the [attempts](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queues#writing-job-classes) method:

```
public function handle()
{
    if ($this->attempts() > 1) {
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I am silly I overlooked that part of laravel documentations.