# Prevent queued job from next attempt after specific error

Tags: php, queue, laravel-8, jobs

Our jobs collect data from external APIs. If one of the jobs errors out because we unexpectedly reach the API daily limit (i.e. HTTP status 429) it is pointless to retry the job again, or even process any similar jobs, till next day.
Is there a way to prevent the current job to be attempted again after a specific event occurs? Ideally I should be able for example to set a flag in the failed job so I can check it on the next attempt (like suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41713245/4530144))

**Edit:** I incorrectly referred to the jobs I didn't want to retry as "failed", however I meant if an error (exception) occurs during the API call. I edited the question.

Comment: I can't think of anything off-hand, but you can probably create a table to log the failures, then check that table at the beginning of the job to see when the last failure happened and if it should bail.

Comment: Have a table with a queue status. Run and deqeue the jobs only if the status is 'ready'.

Comment: How about  adding a class parameter like `$should_retry`, set it to false if the exception occurs and skipping the job right away inside `handle()`if it is set? Will the parameter be available after the first fail?

Comment: No, the class parameter only lives within that job instance. The next job attempt will have it's own instance of the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the solution I was looking for is obvious: just `fail()` the job:

```php
public function handle()
{
    try {
        // execute job stuff and throw a custom
        // exception if a certain event occurs
    } catch (MyCustomException $e) {
        $this->fail($e); // it won't be put back in the queue
    }
}
```